# MVC can't display certain actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. Content is divided into several areas:

- Scheme - for shared functionality like errors
- Pages - for displayed content
- Data - for controllers, that returns JSON data

I don't have any controllers not assigned to areas.

I would like to access `Pages` controllers without typing area's name, and other to be accessed with their area names in route.

So I want to display action `Users` in `Administration` page under `host/Administration/Users`

And I want to display `DatabaseTimeout` Action from `Error` controller under `host/Scheme/Error/DatabaseTimeout`.

Analogously I want `Create` action from `Codes` controller from `Data` area under `host/Data/Codes/Create`.

Now, the problem: `Pages` area works as expected, `Data` area works as expected, `Scheme` area doesn't work as expected. When typing `host/Scheme/Error/DatabaseTimeout` application returns a 404.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Here is part of application code:

Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    }
```

DataAreaRegistration.cs

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Data_default",
            "Data/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "MyWebApplication.Areas.Data.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

PagesAreaRegistration.cs:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Pages_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller="Home",  action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "MyWebApplication.Areas.Pages.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

SchemeAreaRegistration.cs:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Scheme_default",
            "Scheme/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "MyWebApplication.Areas.Scheme.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

AdministrationController.cs from `Pages` area:

```
namespace MyWebApplication.Areas.Pages.Controllers
{
    public class AdministrationController : Controller
    {
         // action methods...
    }
}
```

CodesController.cs from `Data` area:

```
namespace MyWebApplication.Areas.GridData.Controllers
{
    public class CountryCodesController : Controller
    {
         // action methods...
    }
}
```

ErrorController.cs from `Scheme` area:

```
namespace MyWebApplication.Areas.Scheme.Controllers
{
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
         // action methods...
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, now I am really confused.

So under `Scheme` area I have, among others:
 - _Layout.cshtml file, wchich is master page for every showed page
 - Menu.cshtml, which is view for `Menu` action and is rendered on _Layout

`Menu` view is rendered by:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Menu", new { area="Scheme" });}
```

Menu is rendered fine, however...

In menu there is many action links, that directs into different pages, written like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage users", "Users", "Administration", new { area = "Pages" }, null)
```

And that gives route like this: `host/Scheme/Administration/Users`

Eventhough area was specified. I tried to change area parameter into area="", did't help.

Please help me, I am confused and I cant go further with my work. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you type `host/Scheme/Error/DatabaseTimeout` probably application returns a 404 because you don't have a action DatabaseTimeout in ErrorController.cs in `Scheme` area:

```
namespace MyWebApplication.Areas.Scheme.Controllers
{
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
         public ActionResult DatabaseTimeout()
         {
             return View();
         }
    }
}
```

You must create the view ,where you show the error at the user, in your project under `Areas\Scheme\Views\Error\DatabaseTimeout.cshtml`.

The other question --> i think that if you want create a link to action `Index()` in `HomeController` under `Scheme`area you must use this in the views:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "Scheme" }, null)
```

Comment: I DO have action definitions, just did't post it not to make noise.